# Compare equality of instance variables

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby.

```
class X
  attr_accessor :minX, :maxX, :minY, :maxY

  def initialize
    @minX = 0, @maxX = 4, @minY = 0, @maxY = 4

    if @minX == @minY && @maxX == @maxY
        # do stuff
    else
        # not square
    end
  end
end
```

This always enters the else clause - why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it has to do with the way you're defining the instance variables, you'll end up with

```
@maxX=4
@minY=0
@maxY=4
@minX=[0, 4, 0, 4]
```

So it will always be false. If you really want to put them in one line you can do (or follow [Doug R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438988/437049) solution)

```
@minX = 0; @maxX = 4; @minY = 0; @maxY = 4
```

Otherwise, you can put each one of them in a separate line

This has to do with Rubys multiple assignment where:

```
foo, bar = [1, 2]  # foo = 1; bar = 2
foo, bar = 1, 2    # foo = 1; bar = 2
foo, bar = 1       # foo = 1; bar = nil
```

Comment: makes sense, been doing too much Groovy.

Comment: I still get confused with this kind of features when I switch from another language :)

Comment: I think the best solution is to "put each one of them in a separate line". Per the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide): "Don't use ; to separate statements and expressions. As a corollary - use one expression per line."

Comment: Yes, I agree, I did it that way when I tried it in irb before answering the question and I thought it was worth noting. I think Doug's answer it's also good, especially for assigning a returning array from some method.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment should instead look like this, if you want it on one line:

```
@minX, @maxX, @minY, @maxY = 0, 4, 0, 4
```